# Better way to set sliver padding

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, optimization

1. There are 4 ways to get spacing between slivers in Flutter.

```dart
slivers:[
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: 2)),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...),
      ],
```

```dart
slivers:[
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...),
        SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2)),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...),
      ],
```

```dart
slivers:[
        SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2), sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...)),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...),
      ],
```

```dart
slivers:[
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2), child: ...)),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...),
      ],
```

Which one is the best in terms of performance?

2. Same situation but with padding in slivers? Which way is performing better? Which one I should be using?

```dart
slivers:[
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2), child: ...)),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...),
      ],
```

```dart
slivers:[
        SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2), sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...)),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(child: ...),
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

if you open the `SliverPadding` and `SliverToBoxAdapter`, it return the Widget that extends `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget`.

[image]

[image]
IMO, it depends on your need. but I would say it will better using `SliverToBoxAdapter`, because I can have Container child without more padding out of the widget.